# How can I do more complicated queries with an ElementCriteriaModel?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, queries

I need to join my **3rd party table** with a standard **ElementCriteriaModel (ECM)**. I'd like to start with an ordinary ECM, so my plugin will be compatible with any element type which may exist, now or in the future.

By default, an ECM generates a query which joins multiple native tables. According to Brad in [this answer...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2776/45)

> ... think of ElementCriteriaModel as an abstraction on top of DbCommand that makes it easy to search for Elements.

My plugin does not have either a custom Field Type or custom Element Type (which means I can't use `modifyElementsQuery` when retrieving the data).

**How can I expand my ECM query to take additional SQL commands into account?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you've got your ECM, pass it off to the [`buildElementsQuery`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#buildElementsQuery-detail) method...

```
$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
```

**This will convert your ECM into a DbCommand object.** From there, you can make further modifications to the query... like adding a `join` for your 3rd party table.

```
$query->join('myplugintable myplugintable', 'myplugintable.id = elements.id');
$query->order('myplugintable.mysortcolumn');

return $query->queryAll();
```

Comment: Any idea how I would go about using Craft's pagination in this scenario? And is there a way to get the total result count for the query when using a LIMIT clause on the initial ECM?

Comment: @FranzThüs I'd recommend posting that as [a new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to link back to this thread.